# Renew manually Let's Encrypt SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

My Let's Encrypt SSL certificate will expire in 0 day (not yet)...

I use it for a website in nginx & a ubuntu 14.04 server in DigitalOcean.

I have found a folder `/etc/letsencrypt/`, and in the server block:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
```

However, I cannot find for example `letsencrypt-auto`

Does anyone know how to manually renew it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I don't remember how I generated the SSL certificate for the first time. To renew it, by following [this thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04), I first installed `cerbot`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install certbot
```

Then, I need to make sure the path and setting are correct as described in the thread. Then I did

```
sudo certbot renew
```

That's it.

Comment: I personally use an agent/daemon on the host which just implements the acme protocol. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/ https://lxc.systems

Comment: Only a note, If you use manually creation you have to use manually renew with "certbot certonly --manual -d domain.ext" command

Answer (score 0):

This is one command that worked for me.

```
certbot certonly --force-renew -d
```

or for apache

```
sudo certbot renew --cert-name domain.name.here --pre-hook "service apache2 stop" --post-hook "service apache2 start"
```