# Manual renewal of let's encrypt certificate

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt, certbot

When creating my certificate initially I had to do it manually by running the following command.

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual -d www.example.com
```

What is the correct process of renewing the certificate now? Do I simply rerun the same command? I've researched this a bit and the it seems that the automatic renewal is not possible as I had created this certificate manually.

Will renewing the certificate by running the same command create new fullchain.pem, cert.pem, chain.pem and private.pem files. I am asking this because this would require me to update the information on my Compute Engine that is using the certificate I'm trying to renew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renew manually Let's Encrypt SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001078/renew-manually-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using certbot, but I used acme-tiny: https://github.com/diafygi/acme-tiny (I found it on Let's Encrypt page)

In the README you can read about renew: *Step 6: Setup an auto-renew cronjob*

And the conclusion is that renew is only execute again the program with the same files (account key, domain key and csr).

So I supose that if you did a manual request with certbot (I supose that you provide some info like keys) you only need to execute again the command and get your new cert.